# My .ipynb just shows up as raw code and I cant edit anything

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am a beginner to data science and was trying to submit my capstone .ipynb file to github and it would just show the raw code. I then tried to use nbviewer and still raw code. I then tried to open the file in the notebook and again, raw code. I have no idea what happened, everything was running smoothly but now it's all broken.

All the code is in red with a few numbers in green.

https://github.com/penningtron/Thinkful-Projects/blob/master/Capstone.ipynb%20

No error messages.

Comment: I think it is because you somehow have managed to add a space at the end of the file name..

Comment: Oh. My. God. You just saved me. I would have never caught that not in a million years. Thank you so much!